# Is there an easy way to figure out which machines are still running Office 2010 or 2013?

Tags: powershell

I pieced together a powershell script that tells me which versions of office are installed on each computer in the list, but I only want it to output those that are missing the 16.0 basekey so I know which ones still need it. How do I adjust my code to do that?

```
set-location -Path \\main\
Get-Content PClist.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output "$_"
        $reg=[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $_)
        $reg.OpenSubKey('software\Microsoft\Office').GetSubKeyNames() |% {$_} 
    }|
Out-file \\main\officeinstalls.txt
```

Comment: Please update your question to describe in detail what "the 16.0 basekey" refers to, and what difficulty you're having with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do us use conditionals to filter out what you don't want (or find what you do want). You could do something like save the output into an array or object and iterate through it to get only what you want.

## Example

```
$myArray = @(12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,...);

for($i=0;$i -eq $myArray.Count;$i++){
    if($myArray.key[$i] -eq 16){
        #Output my data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *only want it to output those that are missing the 16.0 key* to check for the installation of Office 2016, you could do something like below. This also checks for the 32-bit install if the machine is 64-bit.

```
$result = Get-Content PClist.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Could not connect with computer '$_'"
        # skip this computer and carry on with the next one
        continue
    }

    $baseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $_)

    try {
        $key = $baseKey.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0')
        if (!$key) {
            # if this is a 64-bit machine, test for the 32-bit version of Office 2016
            $key = $baseKey.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0')
        }
        # output the computer name if the '16.0' key was not found
        if (!$key) { $_ }
    }
    catch {}
    finally {
        if ($key)     { $key.Close() }
        if ($baseKey) { $baseKey.Close() }
    }
}
$result | Out-File -FilePath '\\main\NeedToInstallOffice2016.txt' -Force
```